# Filtering duplicate values using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading the documentation to understand the method filter when used with groupby. In order to understand it, I've got the below scenario:

I'm trying to get the duplicate names grouped by city from my DataFrame df. 
Below is my try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city':['LA','LA','LA','LA','NY', 'NY'],
    'name':['Ana','Pedro','Maria','Maria','Peter','Peter'],
    'age':[24, 27, 19, 34, 31, 20],
    'sex':['F','M','F','F','M', 'M'] })

df_filtered = df.groupby('city').filter(lambda x: len(x['name']) >= 2)

df_filtered
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
city    name    age sex
LA      Ana     24  F
LA      Pedro   27  M
LA      Maria   19  F
LA      Maria   34  F
NY      Peter   31  M
NY      Peter   20  M
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
city    name    age sex
LA      Maria   19  F
LA      Maria   34  F
NY      Peter   31  M
NY      Peter   20  M
```

It's not clear to me in which cases I have to use different column names in the "groupby" method and in the "len" inside of the "filter" method

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

How about just `duplicated`:

```
df[df.duplicated(['city', 'name'], keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `groupby` two columns `'city','name'`

```
Yourdf=df.groupby(['city','name']).filter(lambda x : len(x)>=2)
Yourdf
Out[234]: 
  city   name  age sex
2   LA  Maria   19   F
3   LA  Maria   34   F
4   NY  Peter   31   M
5   NY  Peter   20   M
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain in which cases you would specify the column name in the "len(x)[column_name]"?

Comment: @AfonsoSA len(x) equal to len(df) which will return the row number count for dataframe